# Multiple bindings for select angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and I'm finding that working with a select to be a bit tricky. I'm creating a select element:

```
<select ng-model="userToAdd.CollegeCode">
                        <option ng-repeat="college in colleges" value="{{college.CollegeCode}}">{{college.CollegeName}}</option>
                      </select>
```

in ng-model I was able to bind to userToAdd.CollegeCode, but I would also like to bind the text to userToAdd.CollegeName. So far I'm unable to find an example of this. Second, the select is bound to userToAdd.CollegeCode when the object is updated the select option does not select that value. It always starts at the first element. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a $scope.selectedCollege property in your controller, so when a code is selected you can set the corresponding college object as the currently selected object (not sure if you have to iterate all your college objects and find the one, I don't have any code - i would put an ng-click="selectCollege($index)" on the option).
That way you have all possible properties of a college in hand not just the code or the name.

That should resolve both of your issues, as you would retrieve the college name of the newly selected object from $scope.selectedCollege.name.

Comment: This works for getting the data, but I can't seem to make a certain item within the select element selected. So when the userToAdd.CollegeCode is populated I want the select box to select that option.

Comment: make sure you're not trying to set the value of userToAdd.CollegeCode outside of angular's lifecycle (for example for a jquery ajax call or something like that). In that case after you did your changes you also need to call $scope.$apply()